# TableView - Display Image If Cell Boolean Value Is True

Tags: image, javafx, tableview, tablecell

My `TableView` is populated with data from a list of objects. The first column is a Boolean value.

Instead of displaying `True` or `False` in the cell, I would like to display an image if `True` and leave the cell empty if it's `False`.

This is how I populate the `TableView`:

```
colStarred.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("starred"));
colDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));
colTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("time"));
```

I know that I need to use a custom `TableCell` and a `CellValueFactory` but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the documentation (I have not used Java factories in the past).

My research has lead to [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697454/display-image-in-table) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067481/javafx-2-tableview-different-cell-factory-depending-on-the-data-inside-the-cel) regarding [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844042/inserting-images-into-a-tableview-javafx-images-not-displayed) [situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005115/how-to-add-an-image-into-a-javafx-tableview-column), but they all seem to deal with just displaying an image in the cell. I have been unable to find a solution for checking a boolean to determine whether an image should be displayed or not.

How do I check the `starredProperty` of my objects and show an image if it is `True`?

Thank you for all the help everyone has provided me in the past!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume the column to be a `TableColumn<MyItemClass, Boolean>`.

You simply create `TableCell`s that adjust their look according to the item that gets passed to the `updateItem` method.

In this case we'll use a `ImageView` as `graphic` of the cell.

The following images are displayed depending on the item of the cell:

- no image if the cell is empty or contains `null`
- `imageTrue` if the item is `true`
- `imageFalse` otherwise

*You may of course use `imageFalse = null` for an empty cell when the item is `false`.*

```
final Image imageTrue = ...
final Image imageFalse = ...

// set cellfactory
colStarred.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<MyItemClass, Boolean>() {

    private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

    {
        // initialize ImageView + set as graphic
        imageView.setFitWidth(20);
        imageView.setFitHeight(20);
        setGraphic(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        if (empty || item == null) {
            // no image for empty cells
            imageView.setImage(null);
        } else {
            // set image for non-empty cell
            imageView.setImage(item ? imageTrue : imageFalse);
        }
    }

});
```

What happens when the program is displayed is this:

- The `TableView` creates cells needed to display the items using the cellfactories.
- The `TableView` assigns the items to the cells. These items may be changed multiple times. Cells may also become empty after being filled. When this happens the `updateItem` methods of the `TableCell`s are called.

Comment: This worked beautifully. And thank you for explaining what is actually happening behind the scenes. I do understand a bit more now!